# Click a button and download the file content to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

There is a button on a page that provides a JSON file. When you click it, you can download the JSON.

I want to make a JavaScript code, possibly in a browser extension, that clicks this button and download the file content to a variable so I can modify this JSON.

So basically, when the user interacts with the browser extension, it will download the file, modify it, and return the modified version to the user.

In order to provide the user the modified content, maybe I could use something like this?

```js
function download(filename, file) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(file));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  
    element.click();
  
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

But first I need to download it without prompting anything, is it possible?

Comment: `But first I need to download it without prompting anything, is it possible?` => no, it is not

Comment: “*But first I need to download it without prompting anything, is it possible?*” Would you feel comfortable if any arbitrary website on the internet or any browser extension you might install could download files to your machine at-will? My guess is no.

Comment: True  I have to think on something else. Thanks!